# Why do Django apps require `manage.py` for everything instead of using `__init__py`?

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-manage.py

I copied some `manage.py` lines to my `__init__.py` and all my `views` and `models` can be imported from anywhere without requiring `python manage.py shell`:

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
django.setup()
```

That way I can import my submodules in `__init__.py` (further down):

```
import glob

modules = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '*.py'))
__all__ = [os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules
           if os.path.isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
from . import *
```

That way I can do this from any directory:

```
import myproject as mp
mp.models.MyModel.objects.get(field_name='value')
```

This is handy when importing data or doing data migrations away from the project fixtures directory.

Is there anything wrong with this?  If not, why doesn't Django do it this way by default when you `python manage.py startproject`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is there anything wrong with it?  There's nothing wrong with it!  Different dev teams have different preferences.  While django is notoriously opinionated (e.g., all tables should have a single auto-increment primary key field called `id`), how you want to load apps is up to you.
2. Why not do this by default?  I can think of a couple of reasons.  First, several people have their own reusable apps or there are even pypi available django apps that you can install.  If each one of them called `django.setup` django would be setup once for each app.  This also does not account for multiple threads running in a webserver, and [application setup.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)  which might cause resource contention when you don't necessarily want any.  Finally, you'd also lose some control of application setup an initialization order in cases where you need it since the order of imports is now alphabetical instead of via `INSTALLED_APPS`.  Having to write management commands and use them via manage.py seems like a small price to pay for playing well with other apps.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So basically I shouldn't do it if I want my app to be reusable because it might have a resource conflict or `setup()` order problem that I can't anticipate in my environment with my limited set of INSTALLED_APPS. But it's ok at the django project level.